# Information coming up as duplicate Columns phpexcel, mySql

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am retrieving information from the database and exporting it to excel using PHPExcel. The retrieving of the information seems to work fine but Columns duplicate in the excel sheet.
I use the following method to retrieve information:

```
public function monthlyKm($startDate, $endDate, $userid)
    {
        $query = "SELECT  a.`travelDate`,MIN(a.`openning`) AS minimum, MAX(a.`closing`) AS maximum, MAX(a.`closing`)- MIN(a.`openning`) AS diff, b.`destination`
                    FROM kilologs a
                    INNER JOIN users u ON u.`userid` = a.`userid`
                    INNER JOIN destination b ON a.`destid` = b.`destid`
                    WHERE  (a.`travelDate` BETWEEN CAST('".$startDate."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$endDate."' AS DATE))
                    AND a.userid = $userid
                    GROUP BY a.`travelDate`, a.`destid`";
        $query_set = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        return $query_set;

    }
```

Information is supposed to display in the following way:
[image]

But this what I get:

[image]

This is the code for generating the excelsheet:

```
$result_set = $kiloLog->monthlyKm( $startDate,$endDate,$userid);


if(isset($_POST['download']))

{

require_once 'src/PHPExcel.php';
    try{

    $sheet = new PHPExcel();
    $sheet->getActiveSheet()->getSheetView()->setZoomScale(75);

    //set Metadata
    $sheet->getProperties()->setCreator('www.bitsofttech.co.za')
        ->setLastModifiedBy('www.bitsofttech.co.za')
        ->setTitle('Kilometer Logs')
        ->setKeywords('kilos logged report');

    //set default settings
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setVertical(
        PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(
        PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Calibri');
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(12);

    //Get reference to active spreadsheet in workbook
    $sheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $activeSheet = $sheet->getActiveSheet();

    //Set Print Options
    $activeSheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(
        PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        ->setFitToWidth(1)
        ->setFitToHeight(0);

    $activeSheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('&C&B&16' .
        $sheet->getProperties()->getTitle())
        ->setOddFooter('&CPage &P of &N');



    //Populate the sheet with data
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set);

    print_r($row);

    $colHeaders = array_keys($row);
    $col = 'A';
    $rowNum = 1;

    //set the column headings
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A1','Date');
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B1','Opening');
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('C1','Closing');
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('D1','Total');
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E1','Destination');
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);



    //Populate the individual cells
    do{
        $col = 'A';
        $rowNum++;
        foreach($row as $value){
            $activeSheet->setCellValue($col++ . $rowNum, $value);
        }

    }while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result_set));

    $activeSheet->getStyle('A2:A' .$rowNum)->getAlignment()
        ->setHorizontal( PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);

    $activeSheet->getStyle('B2:B' .$rowNum)->getAlignment()
        ->setHorizontal( PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);

    $activeSheet->getStyle('C2:C' .$rowNum)->getAlignment()
        ->setHorizontal( PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);

    $activeSheet->getStyle('E2:E' .$rowNum)->getAlignment()
        ->setHorizontal( PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);

    $activeSheet->getStyle('D2:D' .$rowNum)->getAlignment()
        ->setHorizontal( PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT)
        ->setWrapText(true);


    //Give the spreadsheet a title
    $activeSheet->setTitle('Monthly Logs');


    //Generate the Excel file and download
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Monthlylogs.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($sheet, 'Excel2007');
    ob_end_clean();
    $writer->save('php://output');
    exit();



}catch(Exception $e){

    $error = $e->getMessage();
    echo $error;
}
```

Comment: Where are the duplicates generated? In the data query or in the Excel file generation?

Comment: They are generated in the ExcelSheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errrm... you mean *columns* (i.e. vertical lines; values within a data set) duplicate, right? Because I could not find any duplicate rows (i.e. horizontal lines; data sets).

Your problem is in your loop:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set);
// ...
do{
    // ...
    foreach($row as $value){
        // use $value
    }

} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set));
```

Notice, that you initialize `$row` with **mysql_fetch_assoc**, but for iterating you call out to **mysql_fetch_array**. Here's the method signature and some explanation from the [documentation on mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )
>
> ...
>
> By using **MYSQL_BOTH** (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using **MYSQL_ASSOC**, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using **MYSQL_NUM**, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

**TL;DR**

**answer updated below**:

There are actually two problems:

1. *Problem:* The first line of data (excel row 2) is different from the following lines.

   *Cause:* Different API calls for loop initialization and continuation.

   *Fix:* Use the same API call in both places.
2. *Problem:* Each excel row after line 3 (data row 2 and later) has each value twice.

   *Cause:* `mysql_fetch_array()` will by default create two indices per value: One numeric and one associative (i.e. column name).

   *Fix:* Use different API call or specify `$result_type`.

Solution to both problems wrapped up in a code example:

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($result_set)) !== FALSE) {
    // ...
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! I meant columns, sorry